# How can I use a file of Elisp code as a script?

Tags: message, print, script

I have written a code:

```
;;; calculator.el --- Calculator
;;; Commentary:
;;; Code:

(let ((operand1 (read-number "Enter the first number: "))
      (operand2 (read-number "Enter the second number: ")))
  (princ (format "The sum is %d" (+ operand1 operand2))))
      

(provide 'calculator)
;;; calculator.el ends her
```

I have a problem with disappearing the last program output "The sum is NUMBER". Have you any idea on how to give the program user chance of seeing the final sum printed by princ?

When I type `M-x load-file calculator.el` there's printed `"Loading /home/lester29/calculator.el (source)...done"` in the echo area after giving for example 2 and 3 to `read-number`, not `The sum is 5`.

When I type `eval-buffer` there's nothing printed after feeding `operand1` and `operand2` with 2 and 3.

How can I use a file such as `calculator.el` as a script, as I would do with a file `python calculator.py`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to print it?

This is likely what you want, if you want a user to see the message interactively:

```lisp
(message "The sum is %d" (+ operand1 operand2))
```

`princ` prints to the value of `standard-output` by default: `C-h f princ`.

With Lisp you don't generally load a file just to evaluate code that performs some side effect (other than perhaps changing the program state for some reason, such as adding a function definition).

You can do so, but why would you want to in this case? My crystal ball whispers that you really want to *define a function*, perhaps a command, that reads two numbers and echoes their sum.

Comment: I want to print the message in the minibuffer

Comment: When I type `M-x load-file calculator.el` after executing `read-number` statements I have a message "Loading /home/lester29/calculator.el (source)...done" instead of printed message using message function.

Comment: What's the recommended way to execute `calculator.el` file as script like in Python `python calculator.py`?

Comment: I've modified my question.

Comment: You've changed it to a different question. Please don't do that. Instead, pose a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your changed question, which is now *How to use a file of Elisp code as a script?*...

One answer is to invoke Emacs in batch mode, with command-line argument `--script` or `-x`, and read a Lisp file, as explained in the Emacs manual, node [Initial Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html). E.g.:

> `--script FILE`
>
> Run Emacs in **batch mode** and then read and execute the Lisp code in FILE.
>
> The normal use of this option is in executable script files that run Emacs.
> They can start with this text on the first line
>
> ```lisp
> #! /usr/bin/emacs --script
> ```
>
> `-x`
>
> This option can **only be used in executable script files**, and should be invoked like this:
>
> ```lisp
> #! /usr/bin/emacs -x
> ```
>
> This is like `--script`, but **suppresses loading the init files** (like `--quick`).

---

And in that or any other context, if you use a print function such as `princ` then pay attention to what its doc tells you about *where* it prints.  `C-h f princ` tells you this about its optional arg `PRINTCHARFUN`:

> Optional argument `PRINTCHARFUN` is **the output stream**, which can be one of these:
>
> - a buffer, in which case output is inserted into that buffer at point;
> - a marker, in which case output is inserted at marker's position;
> - a function, in which case that function is called once for each
>   character of `OBJECT`'s printed representation;
> - a symbol, in which case that symbol's function definition is called; or
> - t, in which case the output is displayed in the echo area.
>
> If `PRINTCHARFUN` is omitted, the value of `standard-output` (which see)
> is used instead.

Comment: I recommend `-x`, which means `-Q --script`.

Comment: @shynur: Thanks. Please consider posting that as an answer (with reasons).

Comment: "*Please consider posting that as an answer (with reasons).*" -- I will just add this to your answer as a supplement